# Nexus 4 speaker no longer playing any audio

Tags: nexus-4, speaker

The speaker on my Nexus 4 suddenly stopped playing audio a few days ago. No sound at all, no music, ringtones, etc.

Is this software problem or hardware?

If I reinstall Android 4.3 again manually, will it unmute the speaker?

Comment: Have you checked your settings? Maybe you've activated some silent mode (e.g. via the mute button in the notification area). If not, you could first try a factory-reset before "re-installing". If that doesn't work either, it's likely to be a hardware issue; in that case I'd contact the service.

Comment: thanks Izzy,    i did watever you mentioned but still speaker not working.. if i reinstall android 4.3 will it work ?  right now im using android 4.3.....if install again will it get blocked ? thanks ill wait for  your answer

Comment: If a factory reset didn't solve it, it's more likely to be a hardware issue. A re-install thus won't change anything.

Comment: It was happened to me when I was out during a rainy day. The day after everything was right. I hope your phone "solve" the problem by itself :)

Comment: Check to see if it works with headphones.  If so, try inserting/removing the jack a couple of times; sometimes, the switch in the jack that mutes audio when the headphones are inserted may get some oxidation or foreign matter.  I've had problems with headphone jacks like that on several different devices.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to check the device's settings. It might very well be you just "silenced" your phone one way or the others. There are different places to look for:

- Open the notification area. On many (recent) devices, it holds some shortcuts to frequently used stuff as toggling WiFi, airplane mode, and also mute (i.e. switch between "complete mute", "vibration only", and "normal noise").
- Check all your stuff in the *Settings* menu. Different manufacturers/devices/ROMs have different settings in different places which might cause this
- If you use some "automation tool" like *Tasker*, *Llama*, or the like, check whether it could be one of its profiles

If the above still didn't solve the issue, make a good [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) and then [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) your device. If the device still stays mute after that, it's unlikely to be resolved on a software level, but rather a hardware failure. So in that case, you should contact the service; if the device is still under warranty, they should fix it for free.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone else who has this should also try plugging in headphones to see if that makes any difference.

When it happened to after on a rainy run, I couldn't hear anything through the main speaker so I plugged in some headphones and they were OK.

Happily, once I'd unplugged the headphones, the main speakers were OK again.

I can't be certain but it's my guess that some moisture from the rain had made its way into the headphone socket and the resulting circuit made the phone think that headphones were connected. When I plugged out the headphone jack, maybe it cleared the moisture.

Whatever, it's working now :)

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me.

Just try turning it off and on. (The whole phone)

Answer (score 0):

Turn off bluetooth.  I had same problem and as I looked through the settings I noticed the blue tooth was on.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's a software problem and I had the same problem. I went back to Android 4.3 and then it worked.